# Problema con mapa de Google Maps para Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin.forms

Estoy haciendo un pequeño proyecto sobre integrar Google Maps en Xamarin Forms  y no me sale ningún error solo que no me muestra el mapa, me muestra la pantalla en gris.

```
public class MapPage : ContentPage
{
    Map map;
    public MapPage()
    {
        map = new Map
        {
            IsShowingUser = true,
            HeightRequest = 100,
            WidthRequest = 960,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
        };

        map.MoveToRegion (MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius (new Position (37, -122), Distance.FromMiles (0.3)));       

        var slider = new Slider(1, 18, 1);
        slider.ValueChanged += (sender, e) => {
            var zoomLevel = e.NewValue; 
            var latlongdegrees = 360 / (Math.Pow(2, zoomLevel));
            Debug.WriteLine(zoomLevel + " -> " + latlongdegrees);
            if (map.VisibleRegion != null)
                map.MoveToRegion(new MapSpan(map.VisibleRegion.Center, latlongdegrees, latlongdegrees));
        };

        var street = new Button { Text = "Street" };
        var hybrid = new Button { Text = "Hybrid" };
        var satellite = new Button { Text = "Satellite" };
        street.Clicked += HandleClicked;
        hybrid.Clicked += HandleClicked;
        satellite.Clicked += HandleClicked;
        var segments = new StackLayout
        {
            Spacing = 30,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
            Children = { street, hybrid, satellite }
        };

        var stack = new StackLayout { Spacing = 0 };
        stack.Children.Add(map);
        stack.Children.Add(slider);
        stack.Children.Add(segments);
        Content = stack;

        map.PropertyChanged += (sender, e) => {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.PropertyName + " just changed!");
            if (e.PropertyName == "VisibleRegion" && map.VisibleRegion != null)
                CalculateBoundingCoordinates(map.VisibleRegion);
        };
    }

    void HandleClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var b = sender as Button;
        switch (b.Text)
        {
            case "Street":
                map.MapType = MapType.Street;
                break;
            case "Hybrid":
                map.MapType = MapType.Hybrid;
                break;
            case "Satellite":
                map.MapType = MapType.Satellite;
                break;
        }
    }

    static void CalculateBoundingCoordinates(MapSpan region)
    {
        var center = region.Center;
        var halfheightDegrees = region.LatitudeDegrees / 2;
        var halfwidthDegrees = region.LongitudeDegrees / 2;

        var left = center.Longitude - halfwidthDegrees;
        var right = center.Longitude + halfwidthDegrees;
        var top = center.Latitude + halfheightDegrees;
        var bottom = center.Latitude - halfheightDegrees;

        if (left < -180) left = 180 + (180 + left);
        if (right > 180) right = (right - 180) - 180;

        Debug.WriteLine("Bounding box:");
        Debug.WriteLine("                    " + top);
        Debug.WriteLine("  " + left + "                " + right);
        Debug.WriteLine("                    " + bottom);
    }
}
```

[image: Error]

[image: Clave]

Comment: Has dado de alta tu aplicación en Google? Necesitas una clave de API de Google Maps en tu aplicación para que te aparezcan los mapas.[Aqui (en ingles)](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/maps_and_location/maps/obtaining_a_google_maps_api_key/) están todos los pasos explicados.

Comment: si ya lo di de alta, ya actualice los emuladores también

Comment: Y pusiste la clave de depuración? Hay dos claves, una para depuración y otra para la aplicación publicada

Comment: pues lei el manual al fina te da una clave algo asi(AIzaSyBdVl-cTICSwYKrZ95SuvNw7dbMuDt1KG0) lo cual es la que usas para el proyecto o me equivoco

Comment: En realidad yo nunca lo he usado en Xamarin, solo en Android Studio y en ese caso hay dos claves, es posible que en Xamarin solo sea una. A ver si alguien que tenga experiencia con Xamarin te puede ayudar...

Comment: Tienes que obtener la API-KEY de google maps para poder ejecutarlo, para ello tienes que generarla aquí: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup?hl=es-419 Una vez que la tengas la tienes que poner el el manifest así: <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAbUczduppaViLL1..." /> Si lo has hecho bien debería mostrarte el mapa

Comment: si es lo que hice pero no se porque me sale este error voy a intentar a generar la clave otra vez

Comment: eso es, prueba a genrerarla otra vez y fijate que pones bien el paquete. No me acuerdo si para utilizarlo tienes que firmarlo o no con la clave de produccion, no con la de debug

Comment: ya probe generando de nuevo la API KEY y no funciona, a que te refieres con  la clave de produccion?

Answer (score 0):

Además de especificar el API_KEY del mapa y la versión del Google play Services dentro de la etiqueta  en el AndroidManifest.xml, también es necesario especificar los permisos (los permisos van fuera dela etiqueta `<application>`):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Yo tengo una aplicación usando Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps para tener mapas de Google con compatibidad para ambos sistemas operativos, la estructura de mi AndroidManifest.xml es la siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.company.app" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
    <application android:label="MyApp.Android">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="TU_API_KEY_DEL_MAPA" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false" />
</manifest>
```